# Draw New Posts' Profile!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

New Posts and New Sandbox Posts are chatbots that occupy CGSE's main chatroom, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). They've been doing their jobs for almost one full year now, so I thought I'd make a challenge to honor their contributions!

The challenge is simple: Draw the profile picture of either [New Posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103575/new-posts) (NP) or [New Sandbox Posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103625/sandbox-posts) (NSP). Your program must take as input a boolean value, and draw NP's profile picture if true and NSP's profile picture if false. (They're identical except for the color difference.)

Here are the images you need to output:

[image: New Posts' profile picture; a blue pixel-art cloud with "CGCC" written on it]

[image: New Sandbox Posts' profile picture; same as New Posts', but black instead of blue]

The colors of each image should be #0093E8 (NP) and #000000 (NSP). If your language is unable to output that exact shade of blue you may use the closest equivalent. The background may be white or transparent.

The image can be saved to a file or piped raw to STDOUT in any common image file format, or it can be displayed in a window.

Comment: Note that it's Sandbox Posts (SP for short), New Sandbox Posts is the feed not the bot

Comment: Also, what's the allowed input format? Presumably it doesn't have to be `true` or `false` since not all languages have that? I'd recommend going with the reverse of the normal decision problem rules: allow truthy/falsy, falsy/truthy, or any two consistent values.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Except, of course, the code to draw the images or any other input that could assist in the code.

Comment: @ophact [That's already disallowed as a standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110)

Comment: What if the closest color to the blue and black are the same?

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##vZXPaoNAEMbvPsXgSWsqa1PigslT5BhykI0rBusGsykLJc9uxz/FDcRaqevBcXV/37B@DjPn@DO@sjK7yNdCnJKqyhMJ2UcKOzhYAEQRsvo9mqXCOnLeR2aMCrUdriuoAWrdPLFVvw40hQEq4D3VnS7oPFiOeuLEdKr7xr9R/CFOp4ZjQ3GjVOfnM6rZWc9PhYNOaDU1K0UGqaHT0/9RDz7Tkb9N9c40SJHplN4n2EgvnIlqaz0Z6b4zUq0TlCxHLTmtrGNkWVyUTj0yCxyYJMLbFt4pvMCmXns72LjwhdlqRNwkQraNKoAfnWp1CnUoUZ7X8tDQqMdRfMBEoI6@FHtZZkXqvLn@JT7tZVxKB@vTJrYboeaOFxPFVeSJn4vUwQz4/l5V3w) is the picture as hexa and binary.

Comment: Is [this](https://tio.run/##VY7BSsNAGITvfYxQ6C5p0/yiUFb@7JrQHIrioRWEYtltugmVuEmTmEvtk1TozZNP5RP4BnGpB/EyH8wwwzyrVtVJtS2bkSk2ukuxazGQAHAvAOKbiCMCIA8jMbWc8liElogh8AWLQoRwwTADMWPiEXDGMMZfPuDZvAuRXU9BRLex7Qkb2rZYAggFIL1Kl7lKNBkvV8CeXMbfYJwNawzIboVuzX3DdKtyIv11fx@@pqmuSE29F1USg0Htouzv1yuEw3lKq4aY0dWE2oU1DgaWByMp9Zpi3lRbk5EL6pVqM29U1ZDLydCnruzJ4Q59Q/@@ePZCgoGb8JY736fTh8Ocr8/jWd8d2iWFqYtce3mRkZT4lPb@O0Bp9wM) a valid output?

Comment: @Arnauld "The image can be saved to a file or piped raw to STDOUT **in any common image file format**, or it can be displayed in a window."

Comment: @Makonede My code outputs Unicode characters. Not a dump of any common image file. If anything, it's closer to "displayed in a window".

Comment: @ophact For example, it would be quite convenient for QBasic if I could use 0 for false and 9 for true (which *are* actually falsey and truthy respectively). Having to accept *any* truthy value would be a bit annoying. 0/-1 (which are QBasic's default falsey/truthy values) feels like a good compromise.

Comment: Can we output a matrix of numbers?

Answer (score 3):

### PostScript, <s>132</s> 112 + 4 bytes

```
x{0 .58 .91 setrgbcolor}if
9 9 scale 16 16 false[1 0 0 1 0 0]<~s8S_ka8b3"J.ITILd2AV!!%`RKQ2ZJ`^/O&rW<~>imagemask
```

Uses an ASCII Base-85 string to encode a 16x16 bitmap.

Takes input from command line: `gs -dx=true np-nsp.ps` or `gs -dx=false np-nsp.ps`; +4 bytes for `-dx=`. Output is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 295 bytes

*shorter version thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
#define p putchar(v?-1:b
*s=L"\xcd=C=C=7;104;104;10100.+6100.+6100.+6.3+3++.-.3+3++.-.3+3++.-.3+310.3+310.30.10.30B+30B+\xcf.D.0.D.0.D.0+;+1+3+;+1+3+;+1+3.8+1.0.5.1.0.5.1.C.J6I7I=1O1O1L1O1O1L.R.R.\xdf";main(b,v,n){b%=2;for(v=printf("P6 48 48 255 ");*s;v=!v)for(n=*s++-40;n--;p*232))p*0),p*147);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PS8NAEMXvfooYEbI72WE3f4vDIlgvlYLiuZdm07U5dF2aGgriZ48bNdCDvHm/Ocy8gTHizZhxvGl3tnO7yEf@42T222My3At111zxXq/jzdm0ehlUk5LFn5WUCNUlMYccAMV/XcmZEn/4AJPDZYuPKGcDgQqhC@ICVJiVOHOJT9WqXmn1HLT@Jb4Gbc6tjemw7VzSpEPq2GdzqzOy7@EZ7Y@dO9kkfqmiYjFVVpZRzIj3NOjrgU1bTvMeQBSSnBDkeZZnjHkuWeq5KmpGX@P4DQ)

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 318 bytes

```c
#define p(x)putchar(v?255:b*x)main(b,v,n){unsigned char*s="\xcd=C=C=7;104;104;10100.+6100.+6100.+6.3+3++.-.3+3++.-.3+3++.-.3+310.3+310.30.10.30B+30B+\xcf.D.0.D.0.D.0+;+1+3+;+1+3+;+1+3.8+1.0.5.1.0.5.1.C.J6I7I=1O1O1L1O1O1L.R.R.\xdf";b%=2;for(v=printf("P6 %d %d 255 ",48,48);*s;v=!v)for(n=*s++-40;n--;p(232))p(0),p(147);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDNSsQwFIXxTWplIGnaS9J_DFFw3IwIiusBmSbN2IUxTH8oiE_iZjbzUj6NqTOFWci557uLexO45_sgX7dS7veHvtNR-XNxc6Vq3Zjas2jEtu_k22aHhts4y66rYMTvm8agKhxCgz970zZbUytv2gla4a9HqcTSqeCMpiczSoHk54SEJIRA9F9ndCaFP96Rye5nDfdAZxNOmHt0RigJc7MMZi7hIV8VK8GenB6PhBen9ai0z6uFiLn-cLcJu2tMp5H_nHsLNZU71vPDtHSFedDyQVwOeNo1ImgJiVLKTRRxi-IkxtgiikOLWFpg_nWM8ZTmnOov)

Outputs a [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) image. The image is run-length encoded in the variable `s`.

The boolean input is given via the number of arguments (basically corresponds to `argc % 2`).